# Update table not successful in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I already create an update sql statement, however if I echo the update sql, it shows that the values is updated, but when I check at the table, nothing have been change.
Here is the update statement

```
$updatesql="UPDATE patient_surgery
 set rn_no  ='$rn_no', 
ic_no = '$ic_no',
ot_location = '$ot_location', 
ot_date = '$otdate', 
ward = '$ward',
paying_status = '$paying_status',
class = '$class', 
arrived_fr = '$arrived_fr', 
discharge_to = '$discharge_to'
WHERE rn_no = '$rn_no'
and ot_date = '$otdate'";

if (mysql_query($updatesql))
  {
    echo "<p>successful</p>";
    echo ($updatesql);

  } else {
    echo mysql_error(); 
 }
```

and this is the print_r statement

```
UPDATE patient_surgery set rn_no ='RN001-13', ic_no = '771102016050', ot_location = '3', ot_date = '2014-02-12', ward = '01', paying_status = '2', class = '1', arrived_fr = '2', discharge_to = '3' WHERE rn_no = 'RN001-13' and ot_date = '2014-02-12'
```

and this is the value in the table after updating

"
+ Options
Full texts  Surg_Id     rn_no   ic_no   ot_location     ot_date     ward    paying_status   class   arrived_fr  discharge_to
    Edit Edit   Copy Copy   Delete Delete   rand52fad20d168f69.42722209     RN001-13    771102016050    2   2014-02-10  015     1   2   1   1"

Comment: `this is the value in the table after updating` - What does that imply? Does that mean the values in the table remained as it is, or got updated? It's unclear from your question.

Comment: yes..value in the table has not changed..but when i echo updatesql statmt, it says updated

Comment: where is your query call? ie. `mysql_query($updatesql)`. You are only showing the query you created.

Comment: this is it                                       if (mysql_query($updatesql))
{
 echo "<p>Kemaskini Patient Data Berjaya</p>";
  echo ($updatesql);
  
       echo "No rows updated: <br />\n" . htmlspecialchars($updatesql); 
} else {
echo mysql_error(); 
}

Comment: edit your post with the added code

Answer (score 2):

Your update query is based upon room no. and date. Date gets changed at the time of query submission and when WHERE clause looks for this current date, it doesn't find it and hence nothing happens. (Compare the `ot_date` in your query and in your database)

First of all, you don't have any `primary key` such as id. Your query should be based upon that id which remains unchanged and should not be displayed to update. Think if someone changes room no and date then how your WHERE clause is gonna find the matching record?